# C# Removing multiple disconnected IPC$ remote shares via "net use" command?

Tags: c#, wmi, ipc, share

Issuing the 'Net Use' command from within the CMD prompt shows 50+ disconnected remote IPC$ shares in the following format:

where Name =

Status       Local     Remote                    Network

---

Disconnected           \MACHINE\IPC$      Microsoft Windows Network

How do I enumerate through the list of these shares and kill them if I wanted to write a c# app to do so?

I read somewhere using WMI in conjunction with "win32_share" would work however, it's not returning the expected remote shares.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the [`NetShareEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387%28VS.85%29.aspx) WinApi function to get the list of shares and [`NetShareDel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525386%28VS.85%29.aspx)  to remove the shared reources.

Here you have the Pinvoke for [`NetShareEnum`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/netshareenum.html) with a sample and the [`NetShareDel`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetShareDel.html) as well.